# Bootstrap inline not working as expected with meteor autoforms

Tags: html, css, meteor, twitter-bootstrap-3, meteor-autoform

I have the following in jade:

```
+autoForm(id=decidedChargeBoxForm collection="Products" doc=this type="update" class="form-inline")
    +costFormGroup(name="decidedCharge")
```

And this in html:

```
<template name="costFormGroup">
    <div class="form-group{{#if afFieldIsInvalid name=name}} has-error{{/if}}">
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-addon">$</div>
            {{> afFieldInput name=name placeholder="schemaLabel" label=false}}
        </div>
        {{#if afFieldIsInvalid name=name}}
            <span class="help-block">{{afFieldMessage name=name}}</span>
        {{/if}}
    </div>
</template>
```

I'm taking advantage there of [bootstrap's inline form class](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline), and although it's correctly making the form element not expand to full width, it isn't displaying inline. It's instead breaking to the next line. Here's a screenshot:

[image: bad form]

I threw this into my css:

```
.form-inline {
    display: inline;
}
```

and it works as expected, but I'm confused why step was even necessary.

**Shouldn't the default behavior for the `.form-inline` bootstrap class take care of this in my situation?** What have I done differently that required me to take this extra step?

Answer (score 0):

The `form-inline` class for Bootstrap sets the `display` attribute to `inline-block` or `inline-table` (depending on what additional classes you use on your sub elements), but you have to keep in mind that this is only in the case where the viewport is at least 768px wide. This is stated near the top of [this section](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline) in the Bootstrap documentation. I cannot tell from your screenshot above, but is your viewport not at least 768px wide? This would be the main reason why the Bootstrap class rule definitions are not being properly defined. Also, might you have another package or piece of your own CSS code that is overriding this behavior somehow with different rules that are being rendered after the Bootstrap class rule definitions are being rendered?